# sorting hashes with opencl

Tags: algorithm, sorting, opencl

i have lines of 3 hashes (ie md5, 128bit).
actually plenty of them. think billions, thus they wont fit in main memory.
they are in a file and need to get sorted. 
using gnu sort it takes a long time obviously, but it works.

i think it could be possibly worth to split them ie into a vector of 6 64bit ints and sort them in batches
with opencl, then mergejoin them.
i have a radeon hd 6950 with 2gb at hand.

but i have no experience with opencl.

so the questions:

- which opencl datastructure would i want to use for this task?
- which sorting algo would i use
- could the mergejoin also be accelerated?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is on disk I would just use STLXXL.

http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/

There is OpenCL code.... but try this first :)